# IDE for Django Template Autocomplete

Tags: ide, django, autocomplete

I am looking for an editor for Django projects where the jinja2 templates auto-complete for the given request context.  I saw [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-django-web-application-project-template) showing it for Visual Studio on Windows.  I am looking for options on *nix systems.  I found that PyCharm would do it if you render the template using `render` and label the `template_name` using the string name of your template.  Ex. `return render(request=request, context=context, template_name='template_file')`.

I am looking to get an experience similar to Razor in the .Net realm.